# Wsdl webservice with matlab

Tags: matlab, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to use the function "createClassFromWsdl" with matlab and it gives me a error :

```
createClassFromWsdl('http://localhost/soapserver/server.php?WSDL')
Retrieving document at 'http://localhost/soapserver/server.php?WSDL'
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in createClassFromWsdl>parseWsdl (line 74)
    se = defTypes.getExtensibilityElements().get(0);

Error in createClassFromWsdl (line 34)
[R, schema] = parseWsdl(wsdlUrl);
```

I have download a software called SOAPUI which works perfectly well so I can't found what is wrong...
Here is my simple wsdl file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://localhost/soapserver" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://localhost/soapserver">
<wsdl:message name="printtxtSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="txt" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="printtxtSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="return" type="s:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="SoapDemoSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="printtxt">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:printtxtSoapIn"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:printtxtSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="SoapDemoSoap" type="tns:SoapDemoSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="printtxt">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/soapserver/printtxt"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://localhost/soapserver" parts="txt"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://localhost/soapserver" parts="return"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SoapDemo">
    <wsdl:port name="SoapDemoSoap" binding="tns:SoapDemoSoap">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost/soapserver/server.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: It seems to fail because `wsdl:types` is missing. I don't know if this is not allowed or a bug in matlab.

Comment: I did add <wsdl:types></wsdl:types> just before <wsdl:message name="printtxtSoapIn"> and now I have this error in matlab : Error using createClassFromWsdl>parseWsdl (line 99)
Unspecified Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0

Error in createClassFromWsdl (line 34)
[R, schema] = parseWsdl(wsdlUrl);